# Align Multiple buttons of row to center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I was workin on page i bit confused in row section i was trying to align-items to center it is working perfect but since i check it responsiveness my buttons have to go to next line but instead its size keep getting decrease. I tried to adjust it multiple time but everytime something new comes up.I used to approach to overcome this issue image 1 its not decreasing size while zoom in/out.Image 2 it aligned to center but while zoom in/out the counter/add-to-cart and add to list button keep getting smaller.[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwlBJ.png)[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MBEW.png)

```css
#row-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.pro-button {
  background-color: #ffff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.myButton1 {
  background-color: #117beb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 31px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.addtolist {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 8px 31px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container" id="row-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-sm-12 align-items-center" style="padding-left:0;">
      <div class="align-items-center d-flex">
        <button class="pro-button text-align-left"><strong><a asp-action="detailsnewaudio" asp-controller="product">Print Songbook with Audio</a></strong><br />$@Model.product.UnitPrice</button>
        <button class="pro-button text-align-left"><strong><a asp-action="DetailsNew" asp-controller="product">PDF Songbook with Audio</a></strong><br />$@Model.product.UnitPrice</button>
        <button class="pro-button text-align-left"><strong><a asp-action="detailnew" asp-controller="product">Digital Album</a></strong><br />$@Model.product.UnitPrice</button> @*

        <div class="align-items-center">*@
          <div class="input-group">
            <button class="quantity-minus d-icon-minus"></button>
            <input class="quantity form-control" type="number" min="1" max="1000000">
            <button class="quantity-plus d-icon-plus"></button>
          </div>
          <button id="AddToCartBtn" style="border: 0px; margin-left:5px;" class="myButton1">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i>Add to
                        Cart
                    </button> @*
          <button style="border:0px; padding:0;"><a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home" class="myButton1" style="border: 0px;"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i>Add to Cart</a></button>*@
          <button style="border:0px; margin-left:5px; padding:0;"><a asp-action="" asp-controller="" style="display:inline-block;" class="addtolist">Add to List <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a></button> @*
        </div>*@

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to add `text-nowrap` bootstrap class in your both button. & then check it.

Comment: @HDP thanks for the comment but sadly its not working out is just like as image 2 :/

Comment: Here, You have added <a> link inside button. So, try to add in <a>. For Ex:  class="myButton1 text-nowrap"

Comment: I tried to do it that way but still not responsive.